# $Body_Classes Variable in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, themes

I'm working with the Zen theme in Drupal and have discovered that I can get to the `$body_classes` variable through the `_preprocess_page` function in template.php.

What I'd like to know is exactly how that `$body_classes` variable is populated? Where do the terms such as one-sidebar, etc, come from?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$body_classes` is constructed by `zen_preprocess_page()` in Zen's `template.php` file.

Comment: They are first generated via template_preprocess_page:

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_page/6

Comment: Thanks jhedstrom, that's what I was looking for. That file assigns the class names based on some decisions it makes on variables first defined in the theme.info file. Now I know what I can change/add and what I should leave alone. :-)